# Removing files in a folder by using matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to remove files(maybe, text files) in a folder by using matlab.

Does matlab provide related functions, or are there any other ways?

Comment: delete('YourFile.txt')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete all files with a .mat extension in the /mytests/ folder:

```
 delete('/mytests/*.mat')
```

See this [link](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) for documentation